# C code, why is address 0xFF00 being cast to a struct?

Tags: c, casting, struct, hex

I am trying to understand some Linux kernel driver code written in C for a USB Wi-Fi adapter.  Line `1456` in file `/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/dev.c` (just in case anyone wanted to refer to the kernel code for context) reads:

```
    priv->map = (struct rtl818x_csr *)0xFF00;
```

I am curious about what exactly the right operand is doing here - `(struct rtl818x_csr *)0xFF00;`.  I have been interpreting this as saying "cast memory address `0xFF00` to be of type `rtl818x_csr` and then assign it to `priv->map`".  If my interpretation is correct, what is so special about memory address `0xFF00` that the driver can reliably tell that what it is after will always be at this address?  The other thing I am curious about is that 0xFF00 is only 16-bits.  I would be expecting 32/64-bits if it were casting a memory address.

Can anyone clarify exactly what is going on in this line of code?  I imagine there's a flaw in my understanding of the C syntax.

Comment: It looks like the control/status register for the RTL818x chipset is memory-mapped to address 0xFF00.

Answer (score 2):

Casting an absolute address to a pointer to a structure is a common way in drivers to access the (memory mapped) registers of a device as a normal C structure.

Using `0xff00` works because C doesn't do sign extension of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`0xFF00` is an address in the IO address space of the system. If you look in the code, the address is never directly dereferenced but accessed through IO functions.

For example, in the call

```
rtl818x_iowrite8(priv, &priv->map->EEPROM_CMD,
                 RTL818X_EEPROM_CMD_CONFIG);
```

which then calls Linux kernel low level IO functions.

The address is cast to a pointer to a struct to give access to offsets from the adress, example here:

```
0xFF00 + offsetof(struct rtl818x_csr, EEPROM_CMD)
```

Note that in the `rtl818x_iowrite8` call above, no dereference occurs when passing the `&priv->map->EEPROM_CMD` argument because of the `&` operator, only the address + offset is computed. The dereference is further achieved withtin the internal low level functions called inside `rtl818x_iowrite8`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider this from the device point of view.

Starting at address 0xFF00 inside the address space mapped for the rtl8187 device is a memory range that holds information structured the same way as the rtl818x_csr struct defined [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl818x.h;h=1615f63b02f6128f781364f86a8780b7bdaf9c21;hb=2d534926205db9ffce4bbbde67cb9b2cee4b835c#l18).

So after you logically map that region you can start doing bus reads and writes on it to control the device. Like [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/dev.c;h=71a30b026089eddf6bf08658cf7e3f628992dbc5;hb=2d534926205db9ffce4bbbde67cb9b2cee4b835c#l1481) (had to cut two more hyperlinks because I don't have the reputation necessary to post more than 3, but you get the point). These are just a couple of examples. If you read the entire file you'll see reads and writes are sprinkled everywhere.

In order to understand why that structure looks that way and why 0xFF00 is used instead of 0xBEEF or 0xDEAD you'll have to consult the datasheet for that device.

So if you want to start looking at kernel code, and specially device drivers, you'll have to have more than just the code. You'll need the datasheet or specifications as well. This can be rather difficult to find (see the gazillions of email threads and articles soliciting open documentation from the vendors).

Anyway, I hope I answered your question.
Happy hacking!